# Sorted sublist in list

Tags: python, list, sorting

assume i have

```
a=[[0,1],[2,1],[0,2],[1,3]]
```

i would like to have a result like this

```
b=[[0,1],[0,2],[1,2],[1,3]]
```

The tricky part is to sort the [2,1] to [1,2] and sort the whole list again. I tried

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x: (x[0]))
```

but it give me [[0,1],[0,2],[1,3],[2,1]]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Sort the lists within the list. Because it appears that in the original list `[[0,1],[2,1],[0,2],[1,3]]` the only one that isn't sorted is `[2,1]` and that's the only one in your result that isn't in the right spot (and it's doing this because you're using `x[0]` which in that case is 2). So sort the sub-lists before sorting the list.

Comment: `sorted(sorted(sublist) for sublist in a)`

Comment: thank you peter. That's solved my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to sort the sublist first:

```
print sorted([sorted(i) for i in a])
```

---

**Update** It could be done slightly better, passing a list comprehension to `sorted()` results in a copy of the list being made, so you can just remove it:

```
print sorted(sorted(i) for i in a)
```

Result

```
[[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2], [1, 3]]
```

As @PM2Ring said, using the lambda maybe return the wrong result, it should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the below using comprehension.

```
>>> b=sorted([sorted(s) for s in a])
>>> b
[[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2], [1, 3]]
```

It should work.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
b=sorted([sorted(small_list) for small_list in a ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> [sorted(i) for i in sorted(a, key=lambda x: (min(x), sum(x)))]
[[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2], [1, 3]]
```